# ASP.NET .addClass Error Box Does Not Appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms

I have a page that allows user to select desired schedule to run a task.

[image]

Users can select multiple schedules. *e.g. Daily + Weekly*

Condition: 
If `Weekly` checkbox is ticked, `Select Day of Week` must have at least 1 day selection.

```
var divDay = document.getElementById("divSelectDay");
var execSch = document.getElementById("ddlExecutionSchedule");

var checkbox = execSch.getElementsByTagName("input");
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    if (checkbox[i].checked) {
        if (checkbox[i].value == "Weekly")
            divDay.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        if (checkbox[i].value == "Weekly") {
            divDay.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

function ShowCheckBox(ddlId) {
    var ControlName = document.getElementById(ddlId.id);
    var day = document.getElementById("divSelectDay");

    if (ControlName.value == "Weekly") 
    {
        day.style.display = 'block';
        dat.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        day.style.display = 'none';
        dat.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

//  Toggles Weekly (Day) execution schedule.
function ToggleExecutionSchedule(controlId) {
    var frmControl = document.getElementById(controlId.id);
    var divDay = document.getElementById("divSelectDay");

    var checkbox = frmControl.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
        if (checkbox[i].checked)
        {
            if (checkbox[i].value == "Weekly")
                divDay.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else
        {
            if (checkbox[i].value == "Weekly") {
                divDay.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the same *.ascx* page, I have a `SAVE` button that validates the page input:

```
function SaveGroupCheck() {
    var isValid = true;
    var haveError = false;

    var schedule = document.getElementById("<%=ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID%>").value;
    if (schedule == "Weekly")
    {
        var xday = document.getElementById("<%=chkSelectDay.ClientID%>");
        var checkbox = xday.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
            if (checkbox[i].checked) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter < 1) {
            $("#chkSelectDay").addClass('errorbox');
            $("#divSelectDay").addClass('has-error has-feedback');
            $("#lblSelectDay").addClass('has-error has-feedback');
        haveError = true;
        }
        else {
            $("#chkSelectDay").removeClass('errorbox');
            $("#divSelectDay").removeClass('has-error has-feedback');
            $("#lblSelectDay").removeClass('has-error has-feedback');
        }
    }

    if (!isValid || !haveError) {
        document.getElementById("<%=txtCheckPostback.ClientID%>").value = "Save";
        waitingDialog.show('Saving Changes...');
        __doPostBack();

    }
    else {
        waitingDialog.hide();
        showErrorPopup("Please enter required information for all highlighted fields");
    }
```

Right now, my `SAVE` button allows the settings to be saved when user ticks `Weekly` without `Select Day of Week` selected.

May I know what did I miss? Thank you for your time.

---

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="divExecutionSchedule">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblExecutionSchedule">Execution Schedule</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <asp:CheckboxList ID="ddlExecutionSchedule" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="chkLabel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" onchange="ToggleExecutionSchedule(this)" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="Daily" Value="Daily"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Weekly" Value="Weekly"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckboxList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="alert alert-danger hidden" role="alert" id="executionScheduleError"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="divSelectDay" >
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblSelectDay">Select Day of Week</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkSelectDay" CssClass="chkLabel" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"> 
                <asp:ListItem Value="Monday">Mon</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Tuesday">Tue</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Wednesday">Wed</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Thursday">Thu</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Friday">Fri</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Saturday">Sat</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Sunday">Sun</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="alert alert-danger hidden" role="alert" id="selectDayError"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="text-right">
    <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success btn-md" onclick="return preSave();"><span class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></span>Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you debug the `SaveGroupCheck` function? Is it the 'if' or 'else' part that get executed in that method(the last one: `if (!isValid || !haveError)`) ?

Comment: @Boney yes it was executed. There are other validations, and they were caught at the last part. Just that validation for this module was not detected.

Comment: ok. I meant to ask was it the 'if' or the 'else' clause that got executed?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to `return false;` in the else clause to stop the postback from the button, in case validation fails.

Comment: it was the 'if' that was executed. i will attempt again, will update my post, as deployment in server takes awhile due to concurrent projects

Comment: With your same code I tried and control goes to the 'else' branch, when none of the checkbox is selected. Only thing which I have said before is you need to add `return false;` in the 'else' branch to prevent the postback from button.

Comment: I found out that `var schedule = document.getElementById("<%=ddlExecutionSchedule.ClientID%>").value;` returns a `undefined` value in console.log.